# Send selected value to PHP via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, select

Is it possible to send `$('#select option:selected').val()` as part of the data in a `$.ajax` call? I know it's a numerical value, but I need it for DB purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ajax calls accepts a JSON object to be passed to the server via the `data` options like this:

```
var your_selected_value = $('#select option:selected').val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "your_url",
  data: {selected: your_selected_value},
  success: function(data) {
    // Stuff
  },
  error: function(data) {
    // Stuff
  }
});
```

On the server side you can get the value via the request params.

Comment: I thought so, too, but for whatever the reason my PHP is not getting that `$_POST['select']` is the same as `selected: your_selected_value.`

Comment: You typed `selected` on the data, so you have to type `$_POST['selected']`. Also, try debug your `$_POST` variable, so you can see what is inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.  You can set the data set in the ajax call in the form of a json object.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

`$.ajax({
   url: 'yourUrl.php',
   data: {value: $('#select option:selected').val()},
});`

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

```
var value = $('#select option:selected').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "url",
      data: "selected=".value,
      success: function(data) {
        // Stuff
      }
    });
```

html

```
<input name="selected"....
```